# disable text input after entering some input value in react native

Tags: react-native, textinput

This is the text input that I am using, I want the input field to be disabled after entering a value.I tried using editable props, but it did not help.
I am completely new to react native, please help with an example.

```
<View style={editProfileStyle.textinputView}>
  <TextInput
    style={editProfileStyle.textInput}
    placeholder="Enter your Specialization"
    value={this.state.subQualification}
    onChangeText={subQualification => this.setState({ subQualification: subQualification })} 
  />
</View>
```

Comment: what issue you faced when using inbuilt editable prop ?

Comment: it will be disabled by default. I want the field to be editable initially and disable after entering a value

Comment: in this case just pass `editable={this.state.subQualification.length === 0}` this should do the trick, i have posted the answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the question, since the field should get disabled when it has some value:

```
<View style={editProfileStyle.textinputView}>
              <TextInput
                editable={this.state.subQualification.length === 0}
                style={editProfileStyle.textInput}
                placeholder="Enter your Specialization"
                value={this.state.subQualification}
                onChangeText={subQualification => this.setState({ subQualification: subQualification })} 
              />
</View>
```

using check in your `editable` prop of

`editable={this.state.subQualification.length === 0}` will make field editable when nothing in present in the field

Comment: getting a type error saying that null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.subQualification.length')

Comment: have you initialized your `subQualification` as '' in your state ?

Comment: initialized it as null

Comment: I changed it to an empty string and it works now! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add state and modify your textInput props like this:

```
    state ={
    textDisable: true
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={editProfileStyle.textinputView}>

      <TextInput
                style={editProfileStyle.textInput}
                placeholder="Enter your Specialization"
                value={this.state.subQualification}
                onChangeText={subQualification => this.setState({ subQualification: subQualification })}
                editable={this.state.textDisable}
                onEndEditing={() => this.setState({textDisable: false})} 
              />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

after onsubmit the input should be disable.

Comment: this works, but I have store the state so that it should not change the state every time I reload the page.

Comment: what do you mean store the state?